# Manually sort Views output

Tags: 7, views

Is it possible to manually sort items from Views? I want to be able to define which content goes first and which one's last.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[DraggableViews](http://drupal.org/project/draggableviews) was designed for just this purpose.

Answer (score 3):

The best I've found is to add the integer field to your content type. Then just number your content items in the arbitrary order you want them. When you create a view, you can use that field as your sort, and update them any time. You can even reuse numbers to make a nested inner-sort, so all items with number 3 are sorted alphabetically, for example.

Comment: This is definitely a better solution. Draggable Views is used only for Table format.

Comment: This is not a great solution, what if your entity appears in two views which need ordering? What if an entity appears in two versions of the same view (tagged with two terms)? go with draggable views and create a separate view to modify the order.